# versioning UIDocument with NSFileVersion

Tags: objective-c, ios, icloud

I have a UIDocument subclass that uses iCloud. I would like to implement document versioning but it seems that

```
[NSFileVersion otherVersionsOfItemAtURL:url]
```

returns an empty array, regardless how many times i save the UIDocument in the cloud. so i assume i must be missing something.

What is the proposed workflow to keep older versions of the document around so the user may later choose an older version.

Comment: In case anyone else notices `otherVersionsOfItemAtURL` returning an empty array on OS X, I had this happen when sandboxing prevented my app (in particular, a Swift playground) from reading the file. Running the same thing in the unsandboxed REPL works.